# Does $f(x)=g(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $\mu$ be a positive measure in $\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{M}\right)
>  $, $f$ and $g$ are two measurable functions equal to each other almost everywhere on  $\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{M},\mu\right)
>  $. Assume that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Does $f(x)=g(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

I think the answer is no. Let $f=\chi_{A},g=0$ with $A=\left\{ 1\right\} $. We have $f=g$ a.e but $f(1)=1$, $g(1)=0$. I hope I don't have mistakes.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your $f$ is not continuous. The answer is "it depends on $\mu$".

Comment: Can you explain more precise?

Comment: What does "almost everywhere" mean? Can you see the dependence on $\mu$?

Comment: Chuy, from your questions here, I am thinking you are not ready to solve the problem quoted.  If this is from a book you are reading on your own, then maybe you need to do a more basic book first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set $\{x\colon f(x)\ne g(x)\}$ is open, so if it is not empty then it contains a proper interval. If all of those have positive measure then the proposition holds.

Comment: Can you explain more precise? Why that set is open?

Comment: This set is open because it is the preimage of the open set $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ under the continuous function $f-g$.

Comment: Ehm...of course, thank you @Tomas

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: $\mu$ is a positive measure

Comment: Can you prove the last statement: "If all of those have positive measure then the proposition holds".

Comment: @chuyenvien94: *Hint*: What does "almost everywhere" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *Not necessarily*.

For example, a positive measure in $\mathbb R$ is the uniform measure $\mu$ in $[0,1]$, i.e.,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} f\,d\mu = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.
$$
With respect to this measure, $f=g$ a.e. iff $f(x)=g(x)$ a.e. in $[0,1]$, in the Lebesgue. measure sense. So if $f$ and $g$ are different for all $x\in\mathbb R\smallsetminus [0,1]$, then they are still equal a.e. with respect to $\mu$.

On the other hand, if $f=g$ a.e. with respect to the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb R$, then they are equal everywhere.